# replace nested where condition with join

Tags: sql-server

I have a SQL query that looks like this

```
Select a.* 
From table1 a
where a.ColumnName in
    (Select MAX(b.ColumnName)
    from table2 b
    where b.ColumnName2 in
        (
        Select MAX(c.columnName)
        from table3 c
        Group by c.ColumnName2
        )
    Group by b.ColumnName2
    )
```

I am trying to write this in a join statement. I am positive inner join is what I need to get the right information. If someone could translate this to a join statement, I would be really glad.

Thank you.

EDIT 1:
I tried the typical Join statement that a rookie would.

```
Select a.* 
from table1 a
inner join table2 b
on a.columnname = (Select max(b.columnName) from table2)
inner join table3 c
on b.columnName = (select max(c.columnName) from table3)
```

Obviously, that didn't work because I get 100,000+ results when I should be getting 800. I tried using an alias for table2 and table3 INSIDE the subselect statements and selecting the columnname using THAT alias like this:

```
Select max(bPart.columnName from table2 bPart)
Select max(cPart.columnName from table3 cPart)
```

Still the same result.

Comment: I would start with the making the first subselect a join, like from table2 b left join table3 c on b.b.columnname c.columname.

Comment: This question does not show any research effort.

Comment: If you're after performance an `exists` would likely be faster than the `joins` or the `IN`.  Sample data and expected results would help clarify the question as well.

Comment: @TabAlleman True. I did not look into exists like xQbert suggested OR the left join as Pieter suggested. I just tried different ways of inner join over and over and got stuck in an infinite loop of the same thing in my head. I researched, just not other options than the one I originally thought of.

Comment: When asking a question like this, it is helpful to show the code that you tried that didn't work, what was wrong with the results, and what the desired results were.

Comment: @TabAlleman Edited the question to include my attempts. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PERHAPS....

Though I'm not sure why a join is needed.  Performance wise exists would likely be fastest, and since you're not returning values from table2 or 3 it seems like it would be the best approach.

```
SELECT a.* 
FROM table1 a
INNER JOIN (SELECT MAX(ColumnName) MColumnName, columnname2
            FROM table2
            GROUP BY columnName2) B
  ON A.columnName = B.mColumnName
INNER JOIN (SELECT MAX(columnName) mColumnName
            FROM table3
            GROUP BY ColumnName2) C
  ON B.columname2 = C.MColumnName
```

Comment: B.ColumnName2 is not possible because it is not being selected.

Comment: Originally thought including additional column in the select statement from table2 and table3 would skew the results, but that was just my ignorance. This works fine if I select `ColumnName2` along with `Max(columnName)`

Comment: since columname2 was in the group by it wouldn't skew them.

Comment: Also, I am returning values from table2 and table3. I just did not mention it in the question so as to not complicate it.